# How to access and edit Customer Unit Price via Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0, netsuite-rest-api

Good afternoon,
I need know how I can access to the unit price field outside the customer record, this field is in customer --> Financial SubTab --> and sublist Item Pricing.
I need edit this value via script but now I don't know how I can access to this field and where/when this value is generated because this value is no in the item.
Thanks for your time!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwauE.png)

I was searching how this value is generated, in the record browser I found this about the unit price but I cant found in the item record
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bJiI.png)

Answer (score 0):

ItemPricing it´s a sublist from  customer record you can loop with this

```
   var customer = record.load({
            type: record.Type.CUSTOMER, 
            id: internalid,
            isDynamic: true
        });


for ( var j = 0; j < customer.getLineCount( 'itempricing'); j++ ) {

    var  infoField=customer.getSublistValue( 'itempricing', 'FIELD YOU ARE LOOKING FOR', j ) 

}
```